# How to share on linkedin and twitter using social auth library

Tags: android, twitter, linkedin-api, socialauth

Am developing an application that has the ability to share content on linkedin, facebook and twitter using the socialauth library. It works fine with facebook but it cannot share with twitter and linkedin. I get a warning that "Provider Not Supported"
below is the code am using

```
socialauthadapter.authorize(this, Provider.TWITTER);
......
private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

        try {
            socialauthadapter
                    .updateStory(
                            headtv.getText().toString().trim(),
                            "Africa Progress Panel",
                            "Download APP .",
                            "This year's report calls on African leaders to tackle inequality and demands global community tackle. Let your voice be heard. Download APP",
                            "http://africaprogresspanel.org",
                            Global.SERVER_MAIN_URI
                            + "uploads/pictures/reports/subtopics/"
                            + subtopic_photo,
                            new MessageListener());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

// To get status of message after authentication
public class MessageListener implements SocialAuthListener<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onExecute(String arg0, Integer t) {

        Integer status = t;
        if (status.intValue() == 200 || status.intValue() == 201 ||status.intValue() == 204)
             Toast.makeText(ReportDetails.this, "Message posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and in the logcat this is what am seeing

```
Provider Not Supported
```

how can i go about this

```
NOTE:
```

- all key are correct

Answer (score 1):

You can try my library for social auth and sharing: https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

It's really easy to use, just build Fragment with enabling social networks you need:

```
mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG);

if (mSocialNetworkManager == null) {
    mSocialNetworkManager = SocialNetworkManager.Builder.from(getActivity())
            .twitter(<< TWITTER  API TOKEN  >>, << TWITTER  API SECRET  >>)
            .linkedIn(<< LINKED_IN API TOKEN  >>, << LINKED_IN API SECRET  >>, "r_basicprofile+rw_nus+r_network+w_messages")
            .facebook()
            .googlePlus()
            .build();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(mSocialNetworkManager, SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG).commit();
}
```

And now you can share:

```
mSocialNetworkManager.getTwitterSocialNetwork().requestPostMessage(message,
            new DemoOnPostingCompleteListener(message)
    );

private class DemoOnPostingCompleteListener implements OnPostingCompleteListener {
    private String mmMessage;

    private DemoOnPostingCompleteListener(String message) {
        mmMessage = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostSuccessfully(int socialNetworkID) {
        hideProgress();

        handleSuccess("Success", "Message: '" + mmMessage + "' successfully posted.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int socialNetworkID, String requestID, String errorMessage, Object data) {
        hideProgress();
        handleError(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Please check Github repo for more info, Thanks :)